# Calling for quickSort error c++

Tags: c++, vector, quicksort

So I believe that I have my quicksort method built correctly, but when I call for it in my main function, I get an error that I am stumped on what to do for. Here is my quicksort method:

```
void quickSort(vector<int> & a, int left, int right) {
    if (left + 10 <= right) {
        const int & pivot = median3( a, left, right);

        int i = left, j = right -1;
        for ( ; ; ){
            while(a [++i] < pivot){}
            while(pivot < a[--j]){}
            if(i < j)
                swap(a[i], a[j]);
            else
                break;
        }
        swap(a[i], a[right-1]);

        quickSort(a,left,i-1);
        quickSort(a,i+1,right);
    }
}
```

And here is my main function

```
int main() {
    srand (time(NULL));
    vector<vector<int> > vectorList;

    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        vector<int> tmp(100*pow(2,j));

        for (unsigned int l = 0; l<tmp.size(); l++)
            tmp[l] = (rand() % 20000);

        vectorList.push_back(tmp);
    }
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y != vectorList[0].size(); y++){
        cout << vectorList[0][y] << endl;
    }
    cout << vectorList[0].size() << endl;
    cout << quickSort(vectorList[0], 0, vectorList[0].size()-1) << endl;
    return 0;

}
```

I make the call for quicksort on the second line from the bottom, and i receive an error saying: `no match for 'operator<<' in std::cout << quickSort((* & vectorList.std""vector<blahblahblah`

Comment: `quickSort` returns `void` (which is to say, nothing at all). What are you expecting that line to do?

Comment: I see that now, bhut what do I need to be calling for instead? I figured to sort the first vector in the vector it would be quicksort(vectorList[0][0], but that does not seem to be the case

Answer (score 0):

You might want:

```
quickSort(vectorList[0], 0, vectorList[0].size()-1);
std::copy(vectorList[0].begin(), vectorList[0].end(), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, ", "));
```

Also, as others pointed out, the condition`if (left + 10 <= right)` is a mistake.

Comment: I get the same resolution with your answer, an error message saying "error: no match for 'operator<<' in 'std::cout << quickSort((* & vectorList.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >(0u)), 0, ((int)((& vectorList.std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::operator[]<std::vector<int>, std::allocator<std::vector<int> > >(0u))->std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::size<int, std::allocator<int> >() + 4294967295u)))'|"

Comment: this fixes the problem with printing; see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b48e6ad235fa7662), but there is another problem around here `if (left + 10 <= right) {`, if this is false, no sorting is done at all

Comment: @BondyeLwa, because you are still trying to output a `void` function. Use my code instead.